# When to use WL.App.sendActionToNative?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, ibm-mobilefirst, native

With the new Worklight v6.2, is there any sample scenario (other than updating the text on the UI) which we use WL.App.sendActionToNative?

Can this replace some of the plugins perhaps? Such as the phonedialer plugin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sendActionToNative`, allows you to call native code from your web view. It does not provide any built-in native code for you, you still have to write the native part.

This would allow you to execute code that runs better in native, or use some of the built-in features that iOS or Android provide, or use interesting native code you found online. The limit is your imagination ;) I for one used it to display a native MapView in my application.

In a sense, you are correct, it could replace some plugins you use. However you'd have to write the native part yourself. In your example of the phonedialer plugin you could write native code that handles phone dialing then use `sendActionToNative` to call this feature from JavaScript.

From the native code you can use sendActionToJS to return data back to JavaScript.

Samples of this feature are expected to appear soon on the getting started site (http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html).

In the meantime, you can read the documentation: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/c_action_sender.html?lang=en

Comment: thanks! would love to see more on the differences, pros & cons of using sendActionToNative & sendActionToNative vs plugins.. :D

Comment: oh btw.. i noticed in the config.xml file has the WLActionSenderPlugin feature. I assume that sendActionToNative & sendActionToJS are actually using this plugin.

Assuming that this is right, then most probably, using either plugin or sendActionToNative will have the same effect. The good thing that I can see in using sendActionToNative is that it will be simpler to implement. (I think.. :P)

Comment: Checkout the Worklight Blog there is a recent post that goes in details, provides video and sample code. https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/creating_a_rich_hybrid_application_ui_with_ibm_worklight_foundation_6_2?lang=en